# How to add innerHTML to print page

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot add `innerHTML` to print page. `innerHTML` appears in my HTML page. I can only change to adding `print_html` to existing HTML or replacing `print_html` with existing HTML. I have already had my print CSS so no worries about CSS.

```
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement();
};

function printElement() {
    var print_html = `<div id="printThis">
                        <h2>${current_training.name}</h2>
                         <h6>AÇIKLAMA : ${current_training.description}</h6>`;
    for (var i = 0; i < current_training.exercises.length; i++) {
        var data_image = window.location.origin + "/static/img/" + current_training.exercises[i].exercise._file.image;
        var print_more_html = `
                    <div class="col-3 mb-2" role="document">
                            <img src="${data_image}"     
                                 alt="Card image"/>
                            <div class="btn-center my-shadow">
                                <h6>${current_training.exercises[i].exercise.name}</h6>
                            </div>
                    </div>`;
        print_html += print_more_html;


    }
    print_html += `</div>`;
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    if (!$printSection) {
        $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "$printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);

    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = print_html;
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: The content to print should be in the document already, and made visible/styled appropriately using a print stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've *really* missed something JavaScript is *not* executed on pages when in printing mode in any browser engine.

If you are looking for a quick shortcut you can execute the page in normal mode and then export the DOM (Document Object Model) via the Web Developer tools (right-click on the `html` element and choose the relevant copy menu item for the browser you're using). Then save the exported DOM and print that.

Not the most elegant solution though you're new to this and with some time will come the experience that will make things easier to anticipate.